# Reduction of families to size $\aleph_1$

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Suppose that $X$ is a set and $\mathcal A$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $X = \bigcup \mathcal{A}$ and for every countable $\mathcal{A}_0\subset \mathcal{A}$ we have $X\neq \bigcup \mathcal{A}_0$. Is it possible to find a subfamily $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{A}$ such that the family $\mathcal{C}:=(\mathcal{A}\setminus \mathcal{B}) \cup \{ \bigcup \mathcal{B} \}$

- has cardinality $\aleph_1$,
- $X = \bigcup \mathcal C$, and
- for every countable $\mathcal C_0\subset \mathcal C$ we have $X\neq \bigcup \mathcal C_0$?

Comment: By $\aleph_1$ do you mean the cardinality of the continuum? (i.e. assuming the continuum hypothesis)

Comment: @AntoineGiard, I mean the first uncountable cardinal. No continuum involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily.  For instance, let $X=\omega_2$ and let $\mathcal{A}=\omega_2$ as well (that is, $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of proper initial segments of $X$, which are all the ordinals less than $\omega_2$).  If $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ is unbounded, then $\bigcup \mathcal{B}=X$ and so $\mathcal{C}$ will not work (there is a single element of it that already covers $X$).  If $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ is bounded, then it is bounded by an ordinal $\alpha$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$, so $\mathcal{C}=(\mathcal{A}\setminus\mathcal{B})\cup\{\bigcup\mathcal{B}\}\supseteq\omega_2\setminus\alpha$ has cardinality $\aleph_2$.

Comment: So $x\setminus y\cup z$ doesn't need parentheses? There is some rule which disambiguates it as $(x\setminus y)\cup z$? Where can I find these rules?

Comment: Well, probably it should have parentheses, but the intended meaning in this case seemed clear to me.

Comment: The intention seems clear to me to. However, seeing as we are supposedly creating a repository of good questions and answers, maybe it's worthwhile to restate the question clearly before answering it?